# Output two array in one view (Kohana)

Tags: php, oop, kohana

I have one controller which need to output in one view file and **$_GET param**.
Controller code is:

```
    public function action_register_final() {
    //Detect view file
    $block_center = View::factory('pages/v_register_final');

    $block_center = $this->request->param('user_id');

    //Detect block
    $this->template->block_center = array($block_center);
    }
```

But this code is output only $_GET param... if i remove **$block_center = $this->request->param('user_id');** view is loading good and output. I know i replace **$block_center** but how I can to output both values.
**Thx.**

Answer (score 0):

Watch. You overwrite your variable. I think you need this:

```
public function action_register_final()
{
    // Detect view file
    $this->template = View::factory('pages/v_register_final');

    $this->template->block_center = array($this->request->param('user_id'));
}
```

Or.

```
public function action_register_final()
{
    // Detect view file
    $this->template = View::factory('pages/v_register_final');

    $block_center = this->request->param('user_id');

    $this->template->block_center = array($block_center);
}
```

Not tested. This is what you need? Where is your second array? Try merge.

Comment: **I do this**
`$block_center = View::factory('pages/v_register_final');`
`$block_center->user_id = $this->request->param('user_id');`
`$this->template->block_center = array($block_center);`

Comment: It is possible to share your whole controller?